# How to dark my video background?

Tags: html, css, video, background

It's for video background but it's not working...
Here the html file:

```css
#player {
  object-fit: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop class="player" id="player">
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: Which background are you trying to change? Please be more specific.

Comment: To change the background color of anything in CSS, use `background-color: color value with unit`, which you have done (`background` is a shortcut property and will work as well). If this isn't working, then you have to check your overall syntax for errors. Of course, you can't change the background of the actual video as that is part of the recording.

Comment: did you mean `rgba(0, 0, 0, .50)`?

Answer (score 1):

You have used the background color rgba setting incorrect.

You have:

`background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);`

But the syntex for rgba is:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
```

So your code should look like:

```
#player {
  object-fit: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
}

<video autoplay loop class="player" id="player">
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Sorry for my bad english (I am Dutch :P)

Answer (score 1):

The logic you applied it's ok buy you need to change:

> rgba(0, 0, 0, 50);

To:

> rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);

RGBA color values are an extension of RGB color values with an alpha channel - which specifies the opacity for a color. An RGBA color value is specified with: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha). The alpha parameter is a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque).